# Strange difference in time between add and extend two lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

If I take two list, I can concatenate them with the + operator or with the .extend() method. Both do the same thing.

But if i do `list1=list1+list2` it takes (in my case) **near 0.048ms**. Instead, if I do  `list1.extend(list2)` it takes **<0.001ms** (also in my case).

Why so much difference if they do the same thing? What's the difference and when should I use the + if it's so much slower?

Comment: `list1 + list2` allocates a new list, then assigns it to the name `list1`. `list1.extend(list2)` modifies `list1` in-place, causing less allocations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

This operation creates new list without affecting to any list:

```
list1=list1+list2
```

This operation does not create new one and change first one:

```
list1.extend(list2)
```

Compare second one with:

```
list1 += list2
```

Comment: That makes sense!  I tried the third one and it's even faster, thanks a lot. (I have to wait near 3 minute to select your answer).
Just to clarify, there's a reason why += is faster than extend() other the fact that extend is a method so it has to be called?

Comment: I think += and extend have about same speed

Comment: On about 580k calls += takes about 50 ms less than extend(). It probably depends on my pc.

Answer (score 3):

You want to compare two code segments together? `dis` module is your friend.

```
In [3]: dis.dis("l1=[1, 2, 3];l2=[4, 5, 6];l1=l1+l2")                                                                                                                                                       
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              4 LOAD_CONST               2 (3)
              6 BUILD_LIST               3
              8 STORE_NAME               0 (l1)
             10 LOAD_CONST               3 (4)
             12 LOAD_CONST               4 (5)
             14 LOAD_CONST               5 (6)
             16 BUILD_LIST               3
             18 STORE_NAME               1 (l2)
             20 LOAD_NAME                0 (l1)
             22 LOAD_NAME                1 (l2)
             24 BINARY_ADD
             26 STORE_NAME               0 (l1)
             28 LOAD_CONST               6 (None)
             30 RETURN_VALUE

In [4]: dis.dis("l1=[1, 2, 3];l2=[4, 5, 6];l1.extend(l2)")                                                                                                                                                  
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              4 LOAD_CONST               2 (3)
              6 BUILD_LIST               3
              8 STORE_NAME               0 (l1)
             10 LOAD_CONST               3 (4)
             12 LOAD_CONST               4 (5)
             14 LOAD_CONST               5 (6)
             16 BUILD_LIST               3
             18 STORE_NAME               1 (l2)
             20 LOAD_NAME                0 (l1)
             22 LOAD_METHOD              2 (extend)
             24 LOAD_NAME                1 (l2)
             26 CALL_METHOD              1
             28 POP_TOP
             30 LOAD_CONST               6 (None)
             32 RETURN_VALUE

In [5]:
```

As yo can see, the difference here being between following segments from the first code:

```
         24 BINARY_ADD
         26 STORE_NAME
```

and followings from the second:

```
         22 LOAD_METHOD              2 (extend)
         26 CALL_METHOD              1
         28 POP_TOP
```

All three instructions in second code are roughly as time consuming as the `BINARY_ADD` instruction from the first code. They are in fact doing a similar job, adding items from one list to another. But the extra `STORE_NAME` in first code is causing it to be slower because crating a new object and storing it in memory takes time.

Answer (score 1):

They are not doing the same thing. Consider the following setup:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [4, 5]
list3 = list1
```

If you then run `list1 = list1 + list2` or `list1.extend(list2)` then you get different values in `list3`

```
list1 = list1 + list2
print(list3)  # [1, 2, 3]
```

```
list1.extend(list2)
print(list3)  # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

This happens because operator `+` creates new object for list1, but `extend` modifies list in place and list3 points to the same object.